# Can Windows and Linux developers work together on the same project using C# and ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, monodevelop

If a group of developers are working on a project written using ASP.net and C# in a Windows environment with Visual Studio, is there any way a developer can join their team and work with them on the project in a Linux environment? I know about the open source, cross-platform development framework [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), could this be an option or would the Windows developers have to use this as well for that to work? Is the best option for a Linux developer to just install a Windows partition or can he join them without doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the best option for a Linux
>   developer to just install a Windows
>   partition

Yes, by far. Even better, just get a PC. I've run into so many headaches trying to develop in .NET on Linux. Mono isn't perfect, and never will be.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  Use MonoDevelop and a source management solution like Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MonoDevelop can even load the Visual Studio solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It deppends on many factors, I'd say that if you plan to use third party controls, for example, then you probably better stick to windows and visual studio. If you are going to do P/Invokes (call Win32 api methods) then, again, better stick to windows.

The fact is that many functionality that .Net framework has is only available on the Microsoft redistributable installer/visual studio installer etc. If you are joining a team that already has a project going on and it is linked to any of this namespaces (Microsoft.* comes to mind) then definitely install windows and visual studio, on the other hand, if you are just starting a new project it could be easy to develop on linux with monodevelop as long as you stick to anything that is fully supported by the mono framework.

Another thing you should consider are licenses. If your team already has visual studio and windows licenses it does not make much sense to switch to linux, as much as I love linux and mono/monodevelop the best way to develop for .net is the microsoft stack without a doubt.

What makes sense is to try to comply with mono so that your software can run in unix/linux infrastructure  if you already have it and if switching it to windows server, for example, raises the cost too much.

It's all about the cost, unfortunely, so see these tools just as that, tools, they are the means to an end and just that. If developing and deploying with windows and to windows is cheaper then go ahead, if you have a large unix/linux server set already working and want to deploy into that then use mono, just consider it has a slightly learning curve since it is NOT visual studio/.net *per se*.